# A better way to organize Docco pages

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gruntjs, documentation-generation, docco

I have a large Backbone-style application (~100 files), and I'm trying to select the best method to automate documentation.

I'm experimenting with [docco](http://jashkenas.github.io/docco/), (with [grunt-docco2](https://github.com/eliias/grunt-docco)) but I'm running into issues. With all the files I have list on the left, and then go down past the window with no way to scroll. Is it possible to group them, maybe in style of a dropdown?

Also, is it possible to have an index page generated or something? Docco seems to do 99% of everything I want, but these two things are driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have not found a way to generate a solid table of contents.

However, I have found a way to stop the crazy scrolling.

Where #jump_page is defined in docco.css, change it to :

```
 #jump_page {
    padding: 5px 0 3px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 25px;
    max-height:750px;
    overflow: scroll;
 }
```

I then took my altered stylesheet and passed it in instead using the docco css option.

It's not the best solution, but it will set a maximum height and allow scrolling, so if you have a plethora of files you want to document, you can navigate them more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is irrelevant by now, but there's a project called [Docco Husky](https://github.com/mbrevoort/docco-husky), You should check it out. It's like Docco for projects.

from their README.md:

> A streamlined static site generator for project documentation based on Docco. "Husky" because it's bigger and more irregular than Docco, like Husky Jeans you would buy at Sears back in the day.